# How to get table name based on column value?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist `DDL1` in asp.net webpage which is databound with "Product" column from all the tables in a particular database. Now my problem is, if i select one Product name from `DDL1`, who are the customers having that product name should be bind another dropdownlist of `DDL2`. I have table per customer. I am getting customer names based on the name of the column, but i want customer names based on the column value. What will be the query/stored procedure and code for that? (Asp.Net, Sql-2014, C#).

Comment: showing your tables here might help to answer your question.

Comment: I have 7 tables (A-G) with same column names(Sno,Product,Picture). When the page loaded DDL1 contains "Product" values from all tables, when i select one value from DDL1 then in A-G tables who ever having that Product, should be come in DDL2, who doesn't have that product should not come in DDL2. I want to retrieve table name, i need query/StoredProcedure for this.

Comment: I have 7 different tables (A-G) in database. Each table having same column names(Sno,Product,Picture). When my page loaded there will be only one DDL1 with the "Product" names from all the tables(A-G). There are some common product names also. EX. product "Pen" may contain by table B, table C, table F. When i select "Pen" in DDL1, I want to databound my DDL2 with table names B,C,F. How it will be possible. I want a query to retrieve table name, based on the column value not column name.

Comment: try looking at this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have 7 tables with an schema similar to this:

```
Sno int,
Product varchar,
Picture varchar
```

First you populate a DropDownList with all possible product's name.
Then you select one item of this DropDownList, for example: 'Pen', and you need to know which tables has a Product='Pen'.

One possible solution is building a function that filters every table and fill the second DropDownList.

```
string [] table_name = {"Table1","Table2",...};

private void FillSecondDDL(string product_name)
{
    DDL2.Items.Clear();

    foreach(string tname in table_name)
    {
        if (HasThisProduct(tname, product_name)
        {
            DDL2.Items.Add(tname);
        }
    }
}


private bool HasThisProduct(string table_name, string product_name)
{
    string cmd = string.Format("select Sno from {0} where Product='{1}'"
                               , table_name
                               , product_name);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        DataTable table;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
        adp.Fill(table);

        return table.Rows.Count > 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Just to give you an idea.

Comment: I have 7 tables (A-G) with same column names(Sno,Product,Picture). When the page loaded DDL1 contains "Product" values from all tables, when i select one value from DDL1 then in A-G tables who ever having that Product, should be come in DDL2, who doesn't have that product should not come in DDL2. I want to retrieve table name, i need query/StoredProcedure for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really do not understand what are you trying to do. Can you reformulate the question?

Comment: I have 7 different tables (A-G) in database. Each table having same column names(Sno,Product,Picture). When my page loaded there will be only one DDL1 with the "Product" names from all the tables(A-G). There are some common product names also. EX. product "Pen" may contain by table B, table C, table F. When i select "Pen" in DDL1, I want to databound my DDL2 with table names B,C,F. How it will be possible. I want a query to retrieve table name, based on the column value not column name.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve this. Here is one:

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>       
    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="[YOUR CONNECTION STRING]" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Title] FROM [Products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="[YOUR CONNECTION STRING]" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([ProductId] = @ProductId)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="ProductId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
```

The only C# code you need here is this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```